# bcfips classes equivalent to PrivateKeyInfoFactory and SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, fips

I have the below code. I was trying to find the equivalent classes in bcfips.dll. I found the PrivateKeyInfo, but I'm not sure it's equivalent to PrivateKeyInfoFactory. And what's the equivalent class forSubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory?

```
 var privateKeyInfo = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(_privateKeyParam);
 // Write out an RSA private key with it's associated information as described in PKCS8.
 byte[] serializedPrivateBytes = privateKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();

 var publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(_publicKeyParam);
 byte[] serializedPublicBytes = publicKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();
```